# While running on ios simulator, App crashes when source of imagePicker is Camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app crashes on the simulator but works fine on the device, when I give the source type of imagePicker as Camera. I have already added the permission for camera and photoLibrary in 'plist'.

**Crash log:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type 1 not available'

**Code:**

```
-(void)showImgPickerWithSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.sourceType = sourceType;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
[(UINavigationController *)[[self.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder] presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Does the crash occur since I am trying to access the camera on a simulator? what will be the issue here. What I have missed?

Comment: Can you show us the crashlog please?

Comment: Can you show your crash report? So we can come to know your problem.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type 1 not available'

Comment: You cannot access camera on simulator so you have to add a check if the device contains a camera or not to avoid the crash

Comment: In crash report it says `Source type 1` is not available. `Source type 1` stands for `Camera`. You cannot access Camera from simulator, so when you are trying to access camera from simulator your app crashes because simulator don't have camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isSourceTypeAvailable` method of `UIImagePickerController` to check if given source type is available or not.

```
+ (BOOL)isSourceTypeAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
```

> Returns YES if the device supports the specified source type; NO if
>   the specified source type is not available.
>
> Because a media source may not be present or may be unavailable,
>   devices may not always support all source types. For example, if you
>   attempt to pick an image from the user’s library and the library is
>   empty, this method returns NO. Similarly, if the camera is already in
>   use, this method returns NO.
>
> **Before attempting to use an UIImagePickerController object to pick an image, you must call this method to ensure that the desired source
>   type is available.**

You can add check for source type available or not using below lines of code:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [(UINavigationController *)[[self.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder] presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];     

}
else{

    //it is simulator or device with no camera source

    // handle accordingly

}
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619144-issourcetypeavailable?language=objc

Answer (score 4):

**If you are working in swift then use this code.**

```
if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera))
{
         let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
         myPickerController.delegate = self
         myPickerController.allowsEditing = true
         myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
         self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else
{
         let actionController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Camera is not available",message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
         let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { action -> Void  in
                    //Just dismiss the action sheet
         }
         actionController.addAction(cancelAction)
         self.present(actionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

on the simulator, you can not access the camera so you need to check if the camera is available or not

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
// do your stuff
} else {
//camera not available
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
               UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
               imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
               imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
               imagePickerController.delegate = self;
              [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{}];
 }
else
{
    //Camera not available
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are opening camera on simulator and obviously simulator don't have camera... Proceed giving an alert like this,

```
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                      message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

[myAlertView show];

}
else{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [(UINavigationController *)[[self.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder] presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Hope this may help and have a practice of adding this code always to avoid crashes in **Camera faulty devices**...

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated, use `UIAlertController` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type 1 not available'- This is the reason for app crash means in a simulator we cannot access a camera.Only access the camera in a device so use the following code for avoiding a crash.

```
-(void)showImgPickerWithSourceType:    (UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
picker.sourceType = sourceType;
}
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
[(UINavigationController *)[[self.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder] presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Why is `picker.allowsEditing` set twice?